# When we have two legends in ggplotly, one of them will be removed?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

why `ggplotly ()` function removes one of the legends of `geom-point` in `ggplot2`.

Is there any way to fix it?

Input:

```
input <- data.frame(
  GeneID = rep("ENSG00000162896", 9),
  ExpressionValue = c(0.277122022, 0.453357839, 0.528442331, 
1.362933619, 0.832358131, 0.951361974, 0.073292538, 0.043776198, 0.062623433),
 Coverage = c(92.58126, 83.96996, 85.58937, 99.10806, 93.16097, 94.26496, 91.32948, 77.94179, 80.44060),
 CellType = c("All-Cells", "All-Cells", "All-Cells", "Epithelial", "Epithelial", "Epithelial", "Immune", "Immune", "Immune"),
 virus = c("fluA", "healthy", "SARS-CoV-2", "fluA", "healthy", "SARS-CoV-2", "fluA", "healthy", "SARS-CoV-2"),
GeneName = rep("PIGR", 9),
Secreted = rep(TRUE, 9)
)
```

Code:

```
ggplotly (
      ggplot(input, aes(x=CellType, y = GeneName, colour= ExpressionValue, size=Coverage)) +
      geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
      scale_size_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
      scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("#D9F2FE", "#C1E9FC", "#7ce8ff", "#55d0ff",'#00acdf','#0080bf'), limits = c(min(input$ExpressionValue), max(input$ExpressionValue))) +
      facet_wrap(~ virus, ncol =3)+
      theme_bw()
)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: `cols` is undefined

Comment: @ Quinten,@Nir Graham; codes are updated, thank you.